# Loop Through All SSMS Databases without Recreating Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

**Background Information:**

In Python, I might write something like this if I want to apply the same logic to different values in a list.

```
database_list = ["db_1", "db_2", "db_3"]

for x in range(0,len(database_list),1):
     
     print("the database name is " + database_list[x])
```

**What I am trying to do:**

What I am trying to do in SSMS, is pull a list of DB objects for each database. I created a stored procedure to pull exactly what I want, but I have to run it against each database, so 10 databases mean running it 10 times.

My goal is to do this with a T-SQL query instead of Python.

I tried doing something like this:

```
 exec sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ?; EXEC [dbo].[my_stored_procedure]';
```

The problem with this is, `[dbo].[my_stored_procedure]` has to exist in every database I want to do this in.

How can I create the stored procedure in 1 database, but execute it for all databases or a list of databases that I choose?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to implement "FOR LOOP" logic in SSMS to run 1 stored procedure from 1 database against all databases.

Comment: That's what you're trying to do, it's not the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Implementing what I am trying to do is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: *The problem with this is, dbo.my_stored_procedure has to exist in every database I want to do this in.* So why is this a problem? You want to execute something, so it definitely should exist to be executed, no?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "execute it for all databases" - if you're using sp_msforeachdb you can rference any specific database's procedure with `database.schema.procedure`. Maybe allude to what this procedure is doing?

Comment: I want to take 1 stored procedure in 1 database and execute that same stored procedure in all databases without recreating the stored procedure in each databases.

I want to apply 1 stored procedure from 1 database, but have it work against all databases.

You cannot do this with exec sp_MSforeachdb 'Use? exec [dbo].[proc]';  unless you recreate the stored procedure in that database. This is my problem.

Comment: So you need a dynamic SQL because how do you think (imagine if you were a DBMS) SQL Server will know what object do you access without specifying the database? Procedure is not just some text that is passed and takes a context of destination. For this you need to write a code block instead of procedure

Comment: Would you want the result as a single resultset or as 10 resultsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you are trying to do and if it's what I *think* (you seem reluctant to actually say!) you can do the following:

In the `master` database, create your procedure. Normally you wouldn't do this, but in this case you must prefix it `sp_`

```
use master
go
create procedure sp_testproc as

select top 10 * from sys.tables
go
```

Now if you run this, it will return tables from the `master` database.

If you switch context to another database and `exec master.dbo.sp_testproc`, it will still return tables from the master database.

In `master`, run

```
sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_testproc
```

Now switch context to a different database and `exec master.dbo.sp_testproc`

It will return tables from the database you are using.

Comment: I don't know how much clearer I can make what I'm trying to do seem. I felt like I explained it pretty well. Sometimes I work with people who don't read things if there are more than 50 words and I'm convinced this might be one of those cases. Regardless, I appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: Let me play with what you gave me and I'll get back with you. Thank you!

Comment: I kinda understood what you were asking because I do exactly the same for some global maintenace type jobs - just explaining your procedure needed to be running in the context of the selected database was all really.

Comment: I thought I did that when I typed "How can I create the stored procedure in 1 database, but execute it for all databases or a list of databases that I choose?" in my original post lol.

Comment: Sure - but remember only you know what you mean. for example, you could create a procedure in any database that just prints "hello world" and run that from any other database and it would work just fine - but it's not what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your sproc in master and naming it with an `sp_` prefix:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_sproc_name
AS
 BEGIN
 ...
 END
GO

-- You *may* need to mark it as a system object
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_sprocname
```

See: https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sql-making-a-stored-procedure-available-to-all-databases/

It should then be available in all dbs

Answer (score 0):

Create the stored procedure in the Master database with the `sp_` prefix, and use dynamic SQL in the stored procedure so it resolves object names relative to the current database, rather than the database which contains the stored procedure.

EG

```
use master 
go
CREATE OR ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getobjects]
AS
exec ('
     select *
     from [sys].[objects]
     where is_ms_shipped = 0
     order by type, name
     ')
go

use AdventureWorks2017
exec sp_getobjects
```

Answer (score 0):

@LunchBox - it's your single stored procedure (that you create in one database) that is actually going to need to contain the "exec sp_MSforeach ...." command, and instead of the command to be executed being "EXEC ", it will need to be the actual SQL that you were going to put into the stored proc.

Eg. (inside your single stored procedure)

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ?; SELECT * FROM <table>; UPDATE <another table> SET ...';
```

Think of the stored procedure (that you put into one database) as being no different than your Python code file - if you had actually wanted to achieve the same thing in Python, you would have either needed to create the stored proc in each database, or build the SQL statement string in Python and execute it against each database.

I understand what you thought you might be able to achieve with SQL, but stored procedures really don't work the way you were expecting.  Even when you're in the context of a different database, but you run EXEC <different_db>.stored_proc, that stored proc ends up running in the context of the database in which it exists (not your context database).

Now, the only one issue you may come up against is that the standard sp_MSforeachdb stored proc has a limit of 2000 characters for the command that can be executed (although, it does have multiple "command" parameters, this may not be practical if you were planning on running a very large code block, perhaps with variables that carry all the way through).  If this is something that might impact what you're intending to do, you could do a search online for "sp_MSforeachdb alternatives" - there seem to be a handful that people have created where the command parameter can contain a larger string.